# Get values from a database table by concatening 2 columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'd like to do this query in SQLite:

```
selectQuery = "SELECT " + col_MES + " || " + col_ANO + " AS mes FROM " + TABLE_DESPESA + ";";
```

and I'm using the following code to catch the values:

```
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                meses.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(col_MES)));
            }
        }
```

where meses is a `List<String>`.

But I don't know what should I put on

```
(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(col_MES)))
```

because on the select I'm concatening 2 columns (col_mes and col_ano), so it's not right the getColumnIndex(col_mes), but what should I write?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **alias** of the combined columns.
In your case,

```
meses.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mes")));
```

As defined in your query:

```
selectQuery = "SELECT " + col_MES + " || " + col_ANO + " AS mes FROM " + ...
```

`AS mes` defines "mes" as the alias of your combined field.